# Avoiding patch command to ask for 'File to patch:'

Tags: bash, diff, patch

I am trying to patch a file.

The patch file is in the directory in which the list of files to be patched.

When I run commend

`patch < file.patch`

It prompts me

`File to patch:`

How to avoid this? What should I add in the patch file to automatically detect the filename that it should patch

Comment: What format of patch file are you working with? (Including the first few lines of the file will help identify this.)

Comment: A patch file is normally a unified diff (i.e. the output of `diff -u`), so it puts some filenames at the top that `patch` will recognize. But, the filenames could be `a/subdir/file1` and your current directory is just above `subdir`. You may need to use `patch`'s `-p` option (e.g. `patch -p1 < ...` or `patch -p2 < ...`). Adjust to suit

Comment: Continuing on Craig's comment, the `-pX` option tells `patch` to strip `X` components of the path (slashes) from the left. If you get the error *unable to find* `a/path/to/filename`, `File to patch:` and you know the file is at `path/to/filename` on your system, you would use `path -p1` to strip the `a/` from the beginning of the path allowing `patch` to find the file to patch on your system.

Comment: reg. https://www.pair.com/support/kb/paircloud-diff-and-patch/, maybe `diff -ruN folder1/ folder2/ > patchfile.patch` ?

Answer (score 4):

GNU version of patch includes a `--batch` or `-t` option, which prevents all prompting.

```
-t or --batch
   Suppress  questions  like  -f, but make some different assumptions: skip patches
   whose headers do not contain file names (the same as -f); skip patches for which
   the file has the wrong version for the  Prereq: line in the patch; and assume
   that patches are reversed if they look like they are.
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating the patch with `diff`, the output format, by default, does not includes the filename of the original filename. You can change this with the `-u` option like this...

```
$ diff -u OriginalFile NewFile >NewFile.patch
```

Then, you can simply...

```
$ patch -u <NewFile.patch
```

For further information, read about the [unified GNU `diff` format](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unified-Format.html).

Comment: That doesn't avoid the question/necesity of interaction, no matter which `-p` is specified, at least if `NewFile` is removed. There's no patch manpage or tutorial which explains what happens if the second file is absent - which is the only logical usecase for patching in my opinion.